# How to store int - list pairs in Python?

Tags: python, list, graph, tuples

I have a directional graph structure which I want to pass a template view in Django. So I want to represent the graph with a list of pairs :

```
[42] , [55,67,89]
[2] , [4]
[3] , []
[4] , [1,3,5]
```

this example is a graph where node 42 is connected to nodes 55,67 and 89.

What type of data structure should I use for this task? And I would really appreciate a code example.

**P.S. :** suppose I have implemented the function `get_children(node_id)` so `get_children(1)` can return a list of [2,3,5].

### Edit

Sorry I forgot to mention that node id's are not necessarily like [1,2,3,4], they are obtained from a database so they can be like [42, 55, 67]

### Edit 2:

I need a for loop to iteratively construct this "list of lists", or any other suitable data structure.

### Edit 3: What I'm looking for, as a pseudo-code :

```
node_ids = get_from_database(graph_id)
relations = list_of_lists() # ?
for n in node_ids
    relations.add(key=n , value=get_children(n))
    #or, relations[n] = get_children(n)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Go with dictionary e.g. `a = {1:[2,35], 2: [4], 3:[], }`

Answer (score 1):

If your vertices are enumerated in increasing order, just use a list of lists:

```
G = [[], [2, 3, 5], [4], [], [1, 3, 5]]  # indexing starting with 0

def get_children(g, node_id):
    return g[node_id]

get_children(G, 1)   # returns [2, 3, 5]
```

Update: if vertices aren't in increasing order, the dictionary of lists is your choice:

```
def add_edge(g, x, y):
    if x not in g:
        g[x] = []
    g[x].append(y)

def add_edges(g, x, ys):
    for y in ys:
        add_edge(g, x, y)

# The code corresponding to your pseudocode.
node_ids = get_from_database(graph_id)
relations = {}
for n in node_ids:
    add_edges(relations, n, get_children(n))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the nodes are not necessarily "neighbor numbers"  in my case. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately this assumes an implicit mapping between the node numbers and the children. EDIT: OP updated his question to reflect this

Comment: Yes, using dictionary you can store arbitrary indices.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a simple dictionary to do this:

```
{1: [2,3,5],
 2: [4],
 3: [],
 4: [1,3,5]}
```

And while saving, you can save it in a json serialized form.

You may want to look into using a [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#default) using the default field type in Django.

Comment: Id like to add to this that an easy way of saving that data would be to use pickle: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example

Comment: @OverlordAlex IMO, pickle would be an overkill here if all we have is a simple dictionary.

Comment: True, but I like the simplicity and speed of pickle, especially since we dont know how large this mapping could get. It also allows for more complex structures.

Comment: @OverlordAlex The reason people use pickle in general is so that they can recreate the object back from its pickled representation. For a simple object like dict, you just don't need to use pickling. As for the size and complexity of the dict, as long as the dict is made of simple data types, json would be smaller and much easier to read than the pickled representation. Imagine doing a query in the db shell, and getting random pickled data which doesn't make sense, compared to much more legible json data.

Answer (score 0):

Go with dictionary.

e.g.

```
mapping = {1:[2,35], 2: [4], 3:[], 4: [1,3,5]}
```

Pass this dictionary to template.

e.g.

```
render_to_response('graph_show.html', {'status':True, 'data_dict':mapping}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list structure itself. You might need to take care of the indexing though (python indices begin with 0).

Answer (score 0):

If its always ordered and nothing is skipped you can easily use a list of lists:

```
nodes = [
 [],         # zero indexing
 [2, 3, 5], 
 [4], 
 [], 
 [1, 3, 4], 
]
```

To get the i element just access the list.

```
nodes[1]
```

> [2, 3, 5]

But I would prefer the previous dict version.